# knockoutjs: custom binding fired multiple times and on the wrong binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a question regarding to custom bindings.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm1q89zm/)

There you can see i have 4 custom bindings...everyone binded to the same boolean but every binding gets fired differently.

Is this a Bug?

This great [post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html) says is is fixed in 3.x ... i'm using 3.1.0 and it seems not fixed.

My concrete Problem is:
I want a custom binding, which only gets fired if the model changes and not if another binding changes. (binding four in the fiddle)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customFour = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        console.log('customFour: why get i called on value change? I am not a value binding');
        console.log(value());
        console.log(allBindings.value());
    }
};
```

just look at the fiddle and run it...it says everthing ;)

```
<input data-bind="value: test, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', customFour: test2" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: test2" />
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me?
thx!

Answer (score 2):

The `update` function is called within a `ko.computed` and thus will watch any observables you read within that function. To actually "bind" to the observable, you need to get it's value within the `update` function. Usually a way to do so is like this:

```
var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

Using `ko.unwrap` allows for flexibility in using the binding, allowing you to either provide an observable or a direct value (from an expression, for example).

If you access another binding's value within the `update` function, your binding will also get updated whenever that value changes. You could possibly use `peek` to avoid this.

Regarding `allBindingsAccessor`, it's been changed in 3.0 to [include `get` and `has` methods](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#the-update-callback) that let you better manage which binding value you're accessing.

```
allBindings.get('value')
```

Comment: This answer just saved me a ton of time. You're the best, @Michael Best.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that calling allBindingsAccessor() will evaluate all bindings and will cause the update to be called on each change later on.

Comment: Of course! That is what you can see from the fiddle. And how to avoid this?

Comment: Well, as it's said in this article: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html - "Any time that an observable changes that was accessed as part of the the previous execution of the update function for this binding. Bindings are implemented internally using computed observables, so any observables that have their value accessed create dependencies for the binding." You cannot avoid this if you access `allBindingAccessors` and `value` in your `update` function.

Comment: your linked post is older than mine. And mine says this is fixed in 3.x

Comment: To avoid this I guess you just don't access allBindingsAccessor at all. You can use objects as values if you need a more complex binding. See the template binding for example (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). I think I've bound the template name in a view model in project.